# Font-face don't works

Tags: html, css

I don't know why don't works, because everything is fine.

```
@font-face {
     font-family: 'ModelicaMedium';
     src: url('BwModelica\ttf\BwModelicaSS01-Medium.ttf');
     font-weight: normal;
}


.header p{font-family:ModelicaMedium;font-size:17px;z-index:2;left:50%;margin-left:-293px;text-align:center;position:absolute;top:440px;max-width:586px;color:#fff;}

<div class="header">
<p>Descubra como se livrar dos procesos inúteis e obsoletos do seu negócio, e dar lugar ao que é novo, melhor, e mais eficaz com um os maiores experts de gestão estratégica e de vendas do Brasil</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Is the font `ModelicaMedium` or `Modelica Medium`? Make sure you have the correct font name.

Comment: Is this on your computer or on an internet server?

Answer (score 0):

Well, make sure the font is in a color that it'll be visible, just changed the color of the font -> `color: #000;`

You probably won't see the font you want, because as it's stored on your computer, I can't use it here

```css
@font-face {
     font-family: 'ModelicaMedium';
     src: url('BwModelica\ttf\BwModelicaSS01-Medium.ttf');
     font-weight: normal;
}


.header p {
  font-family: 'ModelicaMedium';
  font-size:17px;
  z-index:2;
  left:50%;
  margin-left:-293px;
  text-align:center;
  position:absolute;
  top:440px;
  max-width:586px;
  color:#000; /*It was #FFF, so in a white background, the font won't show up */
}
```

```html
<div class="header">
<p>Descubra como se livrar dos procesos inúteis e obsoletos do seu negócio, e dar lugar ao que é novo, melhor, e mais eficaz com um os maiores experts de gestão estratégica e de vendas do Brasil</p>
</div>
```

**Testing with another font from the internet, see if that solves your problem :**

```css
@font-face {
     font-family: 'FontTest';
     src: url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto');
     font-weight: normal;
}


.header p {
  font-family: 'FontTest', sans-serif;
  font-size:17px;
  z-index:2;
  left:50%;
  margin-left:-293px;
  text-align:center;
  position:absolute;
  top:440px;
  max-width:586px;
  color:#000; /*It was #FFF, so in a white background, the font won't show up */
}
```

```html
<div class="header">
<p>Descubra como se livrar dos procesos inúteis e obsoletos do seu negócio, e dar lugar ao que é novo, melhor, e mais eficaz com um os maiores experts de gestão estratégica e de vendas do Brasil</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If the font you are incorporating is stored on your computer, load the font using the `src: local()` tag with a server-based resource as a fallback if user-agents that visit are unable to locate your locally stored font using the `src: url()` tag:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: ModelicaMedium;
    src: local("Modelica Medium"),
    local("Modelica-Medium"),
    url(OpenModelicaMedium.ttf);
    font-weight: normal;
}
```

In the above example, the paths given are obviously fictitious and must be changed for compatibility with the local and remote URLs you use.

Answer (score 0):

perhaps it is because you did not list the format?

```
@font-face {
     font-family: 'ModelicaMedium';
     src: url('BwModelica\ttf\BwModelicaSS01-Medium.ttf') format("ttf");
     font-weight: normal;
}
```

or, perhaps your browser does not support the ttf format